# How to replace a double loop in R when specific conditions on lines are needed?

Tags: r, replace, nested-loops

I am currently working on a huge file containing stops/go of several machinas (**about 60**) over a long period (**more than 60 000 rows**).
I have already indexed the table by `1` if the device is `working`, or `0` if it is `not working`.

```
**Date                     n°1    n°2    n°3    n°4    n°5   n°6    n°7**    

1  2011-12-13 00:00:00      0      1      1      1      1      1      1           
2  2011-12-13 01:00:00      0      1      1      1      1      1      1            
3  2011-12-13 02:00:00      0      1      1      1      1      1      1           
4  2011-12-13 03:00:00      0      1      1      1      1      1      1          
5  2011-12-13 04:00:00      0      1      1      1      1      1      1          
6  2011-12-13 05:00:00      0      1      1      1      1      1      1          
7  2011-12-13 06:00:00      0      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

Sometimes the devices *have to be stopped* (not at the same time) for a longer period (*more than 480 hours*) for specific purposes. It is equivalent to **more than 480 sucessive rows of not working**.

I would like to identify those specific periods and separate it from regular stops `0` and replace by `-1` in order to get the beginning date of those long periods.

**I have a code already working**. The problem is that it takes a long time to run... I guess it is because of the nested loop. But I tried and cannot figure out another way of processing using lapply for instance.

```
for (c in 2:ncol(dataframe)){
 for (r in 1:(nrow(dataframe)-480)) {
  if(sum(dataframe[r:(r+480),c])==0)     
  {dataframe[r,c]<-(-1) }
  else 
  {dataframe[r,c]<-dataframe[r,c]}
}}


for (c in 2:ncol(dataframe)){
 for (r in 1:(nrow(dataframe)-1)) {
  if (dataframe[r,c]==-1 && dataframe[r+1,c]==0)
  {dataframe[r+1,c]<-(-1)} 
}}
```

This code replace 0 by (-1) if there are at least 480 following zeros in the column. If there are still some zeros following (the last ones), they will be transformed to "-1".

I just would like to know how I can improve this coding scheme and save computation time...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look on the package **zoo** for rolling computations on a vector. For running through the columns of a dataframe you can use `lapply()` or `sapply()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rle` for that (thanks to @A.Suliman for the helpful comment).

```
f <- function(x, thres = 480, replacement = -1) {
  r <- rle(x)
  r$values <- with(r, replace(values, lengths >= thres & values == 0, replacement))
  inverse.rle(r)
}
```

Apply the function on each column, I use 5 consecutive 0's as an example. (you would need to exclude the first column and set `thres = 480`, i.e. `dat[-1] <- lapply(dat[-1], f)` )

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, f, thres = 5)
dat
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
#1   0  1  1  1  0  0  1
#2   0 -1  0 -1  1  0  0
#3   0 -1  1 -1  0  0  0
#4   1 -1  0 -1  0  1  0
#5   0 -1  0 -1  1  0  1
#6   1 -1  1 -1  0  0 -1
#7   1 -1  0 -1  1  0 -1
#8  -1 -1  0  1 -1  0 -1
#9  -1  1  1  0 -1  1 -1
#10 -1 -1  0  1 -1  0 -1
#11 -1 -1  0  0 -1  1 -1
#12 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1
#13 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  0 -1
#14 -1 -1 -1  0  1  0 -1
#15  1  1 -1  0  1  0  1
#16  0  0 -1  1  1  0  0
#17  1  1 -1  1  0  1  0
#18  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0
#19  0  1 -1  1  1  0  1
#20  1  0 -1  1  0  0  0
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(replicate(7, expr = sample(c(0, 1), 20, TRUE, prob = c(.7, .3))))
```